# Text tokenizer with Stanford NLP sentiment analysis

Tags: stanford-nlp

I saw that Stanford NLP sentiment analysis first tokenize a sentence to phrases. How can I use this service also (i.e. given a sentence and tokenize by the same function as Stanford NLP sentiment analysis)?

Answer (score 1):

Both of these tools (sentence splitting and tokenization) ship as part of the Stanford CoreNLP API. See http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html for basic usage examples.

Comment: Hi, I found tokenizer in Stanford NLP, but it will separate a sentence to words (token). How could I separate a sentence to phrase?

Comment: That's what a (natural language) parser does ... try Stanford Parser.